# CSS and JavaScript failure when launching website in AWS server

Tags: javascript, php, css

I'm really happy with how my PHP website has turned out on LocalHost and am trying to host it on an AWS instance with xampp.

When I view in localhost the website is working with CSS and JavaScript. When I pull to my server all CSS and JavaScript is lost. How can I rectify this?

My folders/file:
index.php
connection.php

1. Folder: Views

layout.php

1. Folder: Pages

   about.php
2. Folder: Public
3. Next level to Public: css

   styles.css
4. Next level to Public: js

   script.js
5. ->Folder: Controllers

pages_controller.php

This is at the content for the page "about.php":

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

In my layout page "layout.php":

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/styles.css" type="text/css">
        
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=5e9ed92b81693d0012e58860&product=image-share-buttons&cms=website' async='async'></script>
```

I am using MVC structure. I do wonder if maybe my scripts/css links are in the correct place. Should I put them all in layout, or the index.php maybe?

Comment: Probably some permissions issue. Are you getting a specific HTTP error code when requesting the CSS and JS files (403, 404, ...)?

Comment: No error at all. I just have all the content showing but its not spaced out correctly/in the right themes.